# How to configure Spring to make JPA (Hibernate) and JDBC (JdbcTemplate or MyBatis) share the same transaction

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, transactions, mybatis

I have a single dataSource, I use Spring 3.0.3, Hibernate 3.5.1 as JPA provider and I use MyBatis 3.0.2 for some queries and my app runs on Tomcat 6. I have a HibernateDAO and a MyBatisDAO, when I call both from the same method which is annotated with @Transactional it looks like they don't share the same transaction, they get different connections. 

How can I make them to do?

I've tried getting a connection from DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource) and I get the one which is used by MyBatis which is strange I thought the problem was in MyBatis config and it can't use JpaTransactionManager. Even calling multiple times DataSoruceUtils.getConnection gives the same connection always, which is ok.

After some googling I've tried spring-instrument-tomcat's classloader (although I don't know if tomcat really uses it :))

partial applicationContext

```xml
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/mybatis/mybatis-config.xml" />
</bean>
```

partial mybatis config

```xml
<settings>
    <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="false" />
    <setting name="useGeneratedKeys" value="false" />
    <setting name="defaultExecutorType" value="REUSE" />
    <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false"/>
</settings>
```

partial persistence.xml

```xml
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What transaction manager should I use for JBDC template When using JPA ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673678/what-transaction-manager-should-i-use-for-jbdc-template-when-using-jpa)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've found the solution here: [What transaction manager should I use for JBDC template When using JPA ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673678/what-transaction-manager-should-i-use-for-jbdc-template-when-using-jpa)

I'm using JpaTransactionManager and not DataSourceTransactionManager.

JavaDoc http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html

> This transaction manager **also supports direct DataSource access within a transaction (i.e. plain JDBC code working with the same DataSource)**. This allows for mixing services which access JPA and services which use plain JDBC (without being aware of JPA)! Application code needs to stick to the same simple Connection lookup pattern as with DataSourceTransactionManager (i.e. DataSourceUtils.getConnection(javax.sql.DataSource) or going through a TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy). **Note that this requires a vendor-specific JpaDialect to be configured.**

After I've added jpaVendorAdapter to my entityManagerFactory config everything works, both JdbcTemplate query and MyBatis runs in the same transaction as expected. Based on the JavaDoc I guess a jpaDialect should be enough but it's 4 a.m. here so I won't try that now :)

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: yes just setting the jpa dialect works `emf.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());`

Answer (score 4):

I haven't got MyBatis in the mix, but as tewe suggested just adding the jpaDialect to the transactionManager does the job too.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

which operates directly on JDBC level. All persistence abstractions (JPA/iBatis and `JdbcTemplate`) are eventually using JDBC, so you need to handle the transactions on the highest common level.

In your case you are using `JpaTransactionManager` that handles transactions via `javax.persistence.EntityTransaction` abstraction. Obviously iBatis is not aware of JPA transaction, hence presumably it works outside of it.

You don't need any class loader/instrumentation magic, should just work.

Comment: "Note that this requires a vendor-specific JpaDialect to be configured." tewe nailed the problem-