# Can JdbcTemplate Share a Common Transaction?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

So I originally posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064953/spring-boot-manually-commit-transaction?noredirect=1#comment100694187_57064953) regarding an issue I was having with mixing JDBC Templates/JPA.

However I'm wondering now if it's even possible to share a common transaction between JDBC Template operations?

Example will update table 'test' in separate transactions.

```
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    public void storeDataInSingleTransaction(List<Test> testEntries) {
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM test", new HashMap<>());
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update("alter table test auto_increment = 1", new HashMap<>());

        String insertTestSQL = "INSERT INTO test VALUES (:id, :name, :value)";
        SqlParameterSource[] testBatch = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(testEntries.toArray());
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertTestSQL, testBatch);
    }
```

EDIT 1: I have tried creating the template/data source manually, with Transactional annotation, but has not been successful for me.

```
    SingleConnectionDataSource dataSource = new SingleConnectionDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(user);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);

    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

Comment: You need to alter table in a real application flow? Why would alter multiple times in real time? Is it a test?

Comment: The example is a test but I do have a need for the above in a real use case. Data in a table needs to be completely refreshed during a user operation. The table in question can still be searched on, so the refresh needs to be in a single transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in Spring, when you call your method from [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) method it should execute as a single connection

> It is not sufficient to tell you simply to annotate your classes with the `@Transactional` annotation, add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to your configuration
>
> you should apply the @Transactional annotation only to methods with public visibility

Also, to use same connection you can set datasorce in context as [SingleConnectionDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SingleConnectionDataSource.html)

> wraps a single JDBC Connection which is not closed after use.

Comment: I tried adding the Transactional annotation to the method and manually setting a SingleConnectionDataSource to a JDBC Template, but unfortunately couldn't get it to work properly. Is there something I'm missing in my implementation possibly? I posted the code in the edit.

Comment: @GetOtterHere the issue probably because `alter table` is DDL statement that will commit, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730621/do-ddl-statements-always-give-you-an-implicit-commit-or-can-you-get-an-implicit also *It is not sufficient to tell you simply to annotate your classes with the @Transactional annotation, add @EnableTransactionManagement to your configuration*

Comment: Ok yea looks like `alter table` was the issue in this case. Removing it fixes the issue I was seeing and keeps everything in a single transaction. Thanks!