# JPA with Spring-security-ACL

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-security, spring-security-acl

is it possible use JPA in spring security ACL, I can see only jdbc implementation. 
here is my JPA setup in beans:

```
<beans:bean id="producerService" class="cz.services.RepositoryProducerService" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="cz.repository" />

<beans:bean id="myEmf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="cz.models" />
    <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="jpaProperties">
        <beans:props>

            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />

    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <!--<property name="password" value="test" /> -->
    <beans:property name="password" value="test1"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

but I have a problem with Transaction manager, beacuse I use `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager`
instead of:

`org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager`.

Main problem is when I start create acl, in first try I have exception transaction must be running, is second try (in broswer back and try it again) is it okay.

Here is error from first try:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Transaction must be running
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService.createOrRetrieveSidPrimaryKey(JdbcMutableAclService.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService$1.setValues(JdbcMutableAclService.java:135)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:899)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:890)
```

can someone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved! :)**

I search that JPA transaction manager in spring

A snippet from Spring 3's JavaDoc:

> This transaction manager also supports direct DataSource access within
>   a transaction (i.e. plain JDBC code working with the same DataSource).
>   This allows for mixing services which access JPA and services which
>   use plain JDBC (without being aware of JPA)!

but problem was in my cglib - I have to use

> `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`

and remove @Transactional from interface JPA repository.

I found solution here too : [What transaction manager should I use for JBDC template When using JPA ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673678/what-transaction-manager-should-i-use-for-jbdc-template-when-using-jpa)

hope someone help it.