# How exactly means partecipate in a given transaction in Spring working with JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am pretty new in Spring and in JPA and I am studying for Spring Core certification and I have some doubts about this question found on the study material:

> Are you able to participate in a given transaction in Spring while
>   working with JPA?

I think that the answer is no because I know that JPA provides configuration options so Spring can manage transactions and the EntityManager but I am absolutly not sure to have correctly understand the question. What exactly means with **participate in a given transaction**.

At the beginning I interpreted as to interact with an existing transaction and this is impossible because a transaction is atomic for definition.

But them into the documentation I found this informations:

**To transparently participate in Spring-driven transactions:**

- **Simply use one of Spring’s FactoryBeans for building the
  EntityManagerFactory**
- **Inject an EntityManager reference with @PersistenceContext**

**Define a transaction manager: JpaTransactionManager**

and show this example:

```
public class JpaOrderRepository implements OrderRepository {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager (EntityManager entityManager) {
        this. entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public Order findById(long orderId) {
        return entityManager.find(Order.class, orderId);
    }
}
```

So is it related to my original question? How?

What exatly do the **@PersistenceContext** annotation and what is the exact role of the **EntityManager** object?

Tnx

Comment: That sounds like a terribly worded question.

Comment: @chrylis Infact I have some difficulties to understand what exactly are asking

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning for the certification and after reading your post I think this excerpt from Spring documentation is what this question is all about:

> Spring JPA also allows a configured JpaTransactionManager to expose a
>   JPA transaction to JDBC access code that accesses the same DataSource,
>   provided that the registered JpaDialect supports retrieval of the
>   underlying JDBC Connection. Out of the box, Spring provides dialects
>   for the EclipseLink, Hibernate and OpenJPA JPA implementations. See
>   the next section for details on the JpaDialect mechanism.

also check [What transaction manager should I use for JBDC template When using JPA ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673678/what-transaction-manager-should-i-use-for-jbdc-template-when-using-jpa)