# Spring Transaction is not rolling back even for unchecked Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

[image]

in the above code i have used hibernate with mysql and the hibernate session is managed by SpringSessionContext (that'y am using sessionFactory.currentSession class under transactional boundary)

the below image (dao layer) is straight forward use case but the exception is not rolled back i have called this method from simple service layer (i.e service layer is calling dao layer for CRUD operation)
i learned about spring proxy mechanism on transaction management in this case this below image class is implementation of Dao interface so spring will create a proxy bean using Jdkdynamic proxy and this method is called from service layer (non transactional class but the expectation was data should not be persisted exception should rollback but  it was persisted in db

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40173587/8430173

Comment: Please share code and not image . You would get better help if you can share the code that calls this method as well .

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate persists dirty objects after the whole transaction process is completed. You should examine the first input method to the last method flow. Hibernate persisting operation is not processed when the save function is called. It stores into a buffer map, and after the transaction completes, it will be processed. Are there any transactions or try-catch blocks in your flow?

Comment: No try catch block the called method is not in transction